# autoload a class in slim behaves strangely

Tags: slim, autoload

I developed an Slim-3 application on my local Vagrant (running on Windows) with standard Ubuntu 1604 env.

In my `composer.json`, I inserted the `autoload` directive:

```
"autoload": {
  "psr-4": {
    "btc\\": "src\btc"
  }
}
```

And in my `src\btc` folder I created a few classes all with `namespace btc` declaration at the top of each PHP class files.

In particular, I have an `http.php` file like this:

```
namespace btc;
class Http {

    const SUCCESS_WITH_OUTPUT = 200;
    const SUCCESS_WITH_NO_OUTPUT = 204;
    const SUCCESS_POST_WITH_OUTPUT = 201; //CREATED
    const FAIL_AUTH = 401;
    const BAD_REQUEST = 400;
    const FAIL_OTHERWISE = 403;
}
```

In my `routes.php` I have this reference:

```
$output = ['res' => 'Method not implemented', 'status'=>btc\Http::BAD_REQUEST];
```

This works fine in my local vagrant machine.

===========

Now I cloned the repo to deploy to my production machine.

- `composer update` runs fine.
- I ran `composer dumpautoload` one more time to create the autoload files.
- Slim app runs OK in the sense that the routes are correctly mapped.
- But it fails saying that `class 'btc/Http' not found` error.

I think this is due to the `btc` namespace not automatically loaded.

Did I miss anything here?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I have located the error that caused this strange behavior: case sensitivity.

As my Linux Vagrant machine is running on Windows, it does NOT care about cases. So `http.php` and `Http.php` is the same.

But in a pure Linux env, these two are different.

Changed to `Http.php` and everything goes fine.

Answer (score 0):

Please use a `/` for all paths in composer.

Example:

```
"autoload": {
  "psr-4": {
    "btc\\": "src/btc/"
  }
}
```

Then run `composer update`.